# Why does pKw first decrease but eventually increase when temperature rises?

Tags: equilibrium, water, ph

[image: pKw vs temperature graph]

I understand the initial decrease in pKw.

$\ce{Heat + H2O (l) <=> H+ (aq)  + OH- (aq)}$

Temperature increases, reaction shifts to the right, so 
$\ce{H+} \text{ and } \ce{OH}$   concentration increases.

Higher $\ce{H+} \text{ and } \ce{OH}$  concentration results in lower $\ce{pK_w}$, as $\ce{pK_w = - log ([H+][OH-])}$

But why then does the $\ce{pK_w}$ start to increase beyond $250$ degrees C?

Comment: I'm afraid your logic behind the decrease isn't exactly OK, or maybe it's just lacking details.

Comment: I think there is a lot you're missing. 25 mPa is about 24.7 atmospheres. At that pressure water boils at 224 C. There is a semi-empirical formula. See https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=154073&view=html

Comment: The closer you come to the boiling point, the less energy the ions gain from hydratisation.